# How to fix "No reply dictionary received from LeakAgent request" error in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

After renaming of my project folder, I can't open `View Memory Graph Hierarchy` tool of debugging. I have fixed my project files and project configuration, and project launches normal, but I need to catch memory leak cases via this tool. How to fix it?

[image: Error message of showing <code>View Memory Graph Hierarchy</code>]
[image]

**Update:**
I have both iPad and iPhone without SIM for testing. With iPad I get the issue, but with iPhone not. It may be related to a device or some system configuration of device. Also I tried to test on my own iPhone with SIM and/or all user settings, then a didn't get the issue.

Comment: Updating Xcode doesn't removes a bug. But after 3 days of coding the problem was gone. I don't know how it was fixed. It will be helpful in same problem occurrences.

Comment: I have the same problem with xcode version 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what can be the reason. Do you still experience this issue? Do you use RxSwift?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue on Xcode 11.4. My project uses RxSwift.

Answer (score 8):

You might run into this issue if you are using Xcode 11.4.1 and trying to view memory graph hierarchy with a simulator with lower OS version (13.0 my case). Using the latest version of the simulator fixes the issue.

Comment: This seems to be the issue, was trying on lower version of simulator that I manually downloaded. Changed the simulator to use the ones that was available by default with the Xcode worked.

Comment: Thanks! This was the case for me on XCode 12.5 on a simulator with iOS 13.3. Had to change to a sim with iOS 14.5

Comment: I've got the same problem with Xcode 14.2 and an iOS 13.5 simulator (iPhone SE 1G) but not with an iOS 16 simulator (iPhone SE 3G). Weird...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. 
It turned out the LeakAgent crashed somehow. So, I figured maybe launch instruments' leak tool should help. So I launched instruments, started the leaks tool and then closed the instruments window (not quit it). Returning back to XCode, the memory graph feature worked. 
Hope this will be of some help.

Comment: i got an error in the instruments as well, which says: Error retrieving leak information

Answer (score 3):

I took the hint that this problem was occurring on one device and not another that it could be related to iOS updates. Sure enough, all my pads were a couple minor version numbers behind.  Once I flashed the newest iOS onto my iPads, the problem resolved itself.

Note: Restarts of macOS, iOS, as well as cleaning DerivedData had no effect.

Answer (score 1):

I got this same error when trying to start Debug Memory Graph in Xcode 11.7 on device with iOS 13.3.1

Resolved by installing iOS 13.7 on device.